# Web view is loading after the transition animation

Tags: iphone

i am using a web view and alsousing the drag event to load next or previous page  on drag right or left event simultaneously but the web loads the next page after fininshing the curl up animation. 
i want to load page data during the animation,

it takes one second to load the new page after animation finishes.
i have checked the loading timing and sequence, web view is loading page and finish loading before starting animation but curlup animation is actually locking the page.

can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to load the next and previous pages on a background thread, so they will be already loaded when the user tries to reach them...
U might want to create an method to get the views (Eg.getView) that takes an NSURL as argument...
and for every swipe you call:

```
NextView= [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getView:) withObject:nextURL];
PrevView= [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(sgetView:) withObject:prevURL];
```